# Loading video from URL to AVPlayer inside RealityKit's VideoMaterial Asynchronously

Tags: arkit, realitykit

I am using RealityKit to overlay a video on top of an image once a reference image is detected. The video should be played from the web using AVPlayer that is inside a VideoMaterial.

I can easily make this work with the code below, but I don't know how to make the loading of the video asynchronous - currently the app freezes for couple of seconds, until the AVPlayer is ready to start playing the video.

I want to turn it into async loading to get rid of the freeze and ideally instead show a SimpleMaterial plane instead.

Current portial of the code that is responsible for detecting the reference image, and creating a ModelEntity with VideoMaterial that contains the AVPlayer:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate{
var parent: ARViewContainer
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!

init(parent: ARViewContainer) {
    self.parent = parent
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchors[0] as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://swiftanytime-content.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SwiftUI-Beginner/Video-Player/iMacAdvertisement.mp4")!)
    videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let videoMaterial = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
    
    let videoPlane = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: Float(imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width), depth: Float(imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height), cornerRadius: 10), materials: [videoMaterial])
    
    if let imageName = imageAnchor.name, imageName  == "referenceimg1" {
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: imageAnchor)
        anchor.addChild(videoPlane)
        parent.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        videoPlayer.play()
    }
}
```